# Slack как пригласить всех участников в канал

Tags: slack

Здравствуйте, искал не нашел в инете.

Есть у нас в команде 20 каналов в slack, и как - то долго приглашать всех по 1 в конкретный канал, есть ли функция или возможность пригласить во все каналы, всех участников сразу ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать возможности SlackAPI
https://api.slack.com
Там есть метод  `users.list` который даст вам список всех пользователей вашей команды. Метод для получения всех открытых каналов `channels.list`
Далее вы можете оперировать списком каналов и пользователей посредством метода `channels.invite`.